# Re-order Excel Sheets based on Sheet names via a macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

If I have 6 sheets in my excel document named and arranged in this sequence : O1, O2, O3, O1_#2,O2#2,O3#3

Will it be possible to write a macro to change the sequence of these sheets?
This is the sequence I am looking for:
O1, O1#2, O2, O2#2, O3, O3#2

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you need to sort sheets in alphabetical order:

```
Sub SortSheets()

    Dim shNames As Collection
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim temp As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set shNames = New Collection

    'add sheet names in collection
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        shNames.Add sh.Name, sh.Name
    Next sh

    'bubble sort
    For i = 1 To shNames.Count - 1
        For j = i + 1 To shNames.Count
            If shNames(i) > shNames(j) Then
               temp = shNames(j)
               shNames.Remove j
               shNames.Add temp, temp, i
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

   ' move sheets
   For i = shNames.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
       Worksheets(shNames(i)).Move Before:=Sheets(1)
   Next i

End Sub
```