# vba sort worksheets: why capital / non-capital?

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, worksheet

I have a code which sorts my worksheets from sheet 9 until the last sheet. I found that it works perfectly. The only thing I do not understand: the code somehow sorts capitals first and after that, all sheets with names that do not start with capitals follow. 
Why is that?

this is the sort code:

```
Sub SortSheets()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim I As Integer, J As Integer

For I = 9 To Sheets.Count
  For J = I + 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(J).Name < Sheets(I).Name Then
      Worksheets(J).Move before:=Worksheets(I)
    End If
  Next J
Next I

End Sub
```

It now sorts all the right worksheets but first, all the worksheets with a name that starts with a capital are sorted, and after that, all the sheets with names that start with a non-capital are sorted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146857/re-order-excel-sheets-based-on-sheet-names-via-a-macro/21147116#21147116

Comment: `If LCase(Sheets(J).Name) < LCase(Sheets(I).Name) Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the code provided by simoco fixes the sorting - the reason why the capital letters were sorted first is because they have lower [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Here's a table for reference.
[image: ASCII values]

You can get the ASCII value of a string in VBA using the `Asc(myString)` function.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it and now I understand A is not the same as a although both are the same letter. So I can choose to adjust the code using Lcase or evenso Ucase to the right sorting. Thanks!